# Spaces around multiplication and division operators are deleted by IDE, how to keep them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, resharper-7.0

I'm using Visual Studio with ReSharper, and whenever I write something like

```
a * b
```

it gets changed to

```
a*b
```

Is it a Visual Studio setting or a ReSharper setting? What exactly should I change?

Comment: This auto formatting has been driving me crazy last 3 years!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Spaces.

In the "Around Operators" section, check the box next to "Multiplicative operators (*,/,%)".

Comment: This doesn't make any difference for me.

Comment: The "Around Operators" section is now called "Around Binary Operators". Thanks much!